# Расшифровать TLS без сокета

Tags: python, asyncio, tls

**Остался вопрос: как понять что соединение готово к передаче?**

Пишу сервер, в протоколе есть проксированный TLS.

Сообщения нормальные для TLS, но упакованные.

Самый простой способ расшифровать TLS это создать пару сокетов и один врапнуть.

```
import socket
import ssl
context = ssl.create_default_context()
sock_cache = dict()

def processor(data, session_id):
    sp = sock_cache.get(session_id)
    if sp:
       a,b = sp
    else:
       a,b = socket.socketpair()
       a = context.wrap_socket(a, server_side=True)
       sock_cache[session_id] = a,b

    b.send(data)
    data = a.recv(4096)
    if data:
       answer = process(data)
       a.send(answer)
       sock_cache.pop(session_id)
    else:
       pass # handshake

    return b.recv(4096)
```

Сделал бы отдельный сервер, но данные из пакета нужны тут, а не вдругом сервере.

Как избавится от создания пары сокетов? следовательно от блокировок и кеша

Похоже нашел https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/bec4186c67345f1e6cd3f8a531bc228f14d7ed7b/Lib/ssl.py#L812

Осталось разобраться как с этим работать

```
import ssl

incom = ssl.MemoryBIO()
outcom = ssl.MemoryBIO()

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_SERVER)
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="ssl_cert.pem", keyfile="ssl_key.pem")

sslo = context.wrap_bio(incom, outcom, server_side=True)

client_hello =  b"\x16\x03\x01\x01\x91\x01\x00\x01\x8d\x03\x03D\x93\xe7\xd7w\x1a\xd4G\xebM\xbe@\xb3\xc2\x93\xb7m\xc9\x01\x90\xb9!\x8d\xef<\xbe,\xab\xb2\xace\xa1 N\x81\xebgxn\xe7\x81)8\xaf\xec\xc0_\xe8\x11x\xb4\xc5\xf5t(Y\xd5X9\xa7\xe1\x99\\\x85\xe4\x00\x96\x13\x02\x13\x03\x13\x01\xc0,\xc00\x00\xa3\x00\x9f\xcc\xa9\xcc\xa8\xcc\xaa\xc0\xaf\xc0\xad\xc0\xa3\xc0\x9f\xc0]\xc0a\xc0W\xc0S\xc0+\xc0/\x00\xa2\x00\x9e\xc0\xae\xc0\xac\xc0\xa2\xc0\x9e\xc0\\\xc0`\xc0V\xc0R\xc0$\xc0(\x00k\x00j\xc0s\xc0w\x00\xc4\x00\xc3\xc0#\xc0'\x00g\x00@\xc0r\xc0v\x00\xbe\x00\xbd\xc0\n\xc0\x14\x009\x008\x00\x88\x00\x87\xc0\t\xc0\x13\x003\x002\x00E\x00D\x00\x9d\xc0\xa1\xc0\x9d\xc0Q\x00\x9c\xc0\xa0\xc0\x9c\xc0P\x00=\x00\xc0\x00<\x00\xba\x005\x00\x84\x00/\x00A\x00\xff\x01\x00\x00\xae\x00\x0b\x00\x04\x03\x00\x01\x02\x00\n\x00\x04\x00\x02\x00\x17\x00#\x00\x00\x00\x16\x00\x00\x00\x17\x00\x00\x00\r\x000\x00.\x04\x03\x05\x03\x06\x03\x08\x07\x08\x08\x08\t\x08\n\x08\x0b\x08\x04\x08\x05\x08\x06\x04\x01\x05\x01\x06\x01\x03\x03\x02\x03\x03\x01\x02\x01\x03\x02\x02\x02\x04\x02\x05\x02\x06\x02\x00+\x00\t\x08\x03\x04\x03\x03\x03\x02\x03\x01\x00-\x00\x02\x01\x01\x003\x00G\x00E\x00\x17\x00A\x04\xac\x82\x10z=\x8do\x06w\xd1\xc5\x16\xd5\x8e\x8a$!\xb4\xca\xdc\x97hz~{U y\xf9:\xc7\x9f\xe3\xb4\x0e+\xc9\x11\x1f\xe8\xb2\xb6'U\x90\xa2Urf\xa9\xc3\xb6\xd2\xbd\x15\xd4\x94\xd7\xb5|\xbes\t\xef"
```

Остановился на том что не понятно куда засунуть это client_hello. Пробовал везде, но получаю ошибку `ssl.SSLWantReadError: The operation did not complete (read) (_ssl.c:1108)`

Comment: От балды предположу создать фейковый объект с интерфейсом сокета, но пробовать лень и вообще костыль

Comment: @andreymal ну создавать пару сокетов на пару милисекунд не хочется так...

Comment: по всей видимости создатели модуля ssl не оставили такой возможности. насколько я знаю, это обертка над openssl, и там такая возможность есть. можно создавать tls соединения над любым потоком данных, не только на открытом сокете. я делал такую обертку для .net

Comment: @Zergatul если начинаешь в проекте использовать openssl через прямые вызовы - начинаются проблемы с Виндовс...

Comment: @eri какие проблемы с виндовс? в меня было всё ок

Comment: да когда на одно приложение пишешь, то особо то и нет. а когда либ под несколько проектов, то искть lineay32.dll, то libcrypto.dll - родной сборки нет, компилить самому и поддерживать тяжело...

Comment: Вы не могли бы пояснить, что именно хотите добиться? Что значит "расшифровать TLS"? Правильно я понимаю, что у вас есть записанная последовательность сообщений TLS, и вы хотите её воспроизвести локально, чтобы расшифровать данные?
Полагаю, что ничего не выйдет. На этапе handshake сокет `a` запустит Диффи-Хеллмана для генерации ключей, и на этом ваша  replay-атака закончится, так как запись клиентского сообщения Finished не соответствует новому ключу, который сгенерировал openssl для сокета `a`.

Comment: @PakUula прилетает пакет, внутри которого куча заголовков разного уровня и кусочек tls. Вот этот кусочек хендшейк, его принимаем в  тлс и отдаем сертификат сервера. Пакуем и отправляем обратно. Потом прилетает ещё кусочек с данными - его отпрвляем в выше хендшейкнутый тлс объект и получаем данные. В расшифрованном виде.

Comment: @PakUula я делаю не атаку, а сервер для приема сообщений

Comment: Понял! Я делал такую штуку в Java, там можно отделить `SSLEngine` от потоков ввода-вывода. В OpenSSL есть аналогичная возможность прикрутить к SSL-движку произвольные потоки ввода-вывода, в том числе читающие-пишущие в память. Но как это сделать в Python через предоставленный binding - к сожалению, не знаю.

Comment: потоки и стандартную обвяку нашел в стандартной либе питона, но не понятно где тут вход где выход

Comment: разобрался вроде.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для теста вот что получилось:

```
import ssl
import socket

incom = ssl.MemoryBIO()
outcom = ssl.MemoryBIO()

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="ssl_cert.pem", keyfile="ssl_key.pem")

sslo = context.wrap_bio(incom, outcom, server_side=True)

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('', 8001))
serversocket.listen(1)

(clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()


message = b''

while True:
    req = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    incom.write(req)
    try:
        sslo.do_handshake()
        data = sslo.read()
        message += data
        print(data)
        if not data:
            break
    except ssl.SSLWantReadError:
        resp = outcom.read()
        clientsocket.send(resp)


print(message)
```

Успешно принял сообщения от

```
cat | socat stdio openssl-connect:127.1:8001,verify=0
```

Остался вопрос: как понять что соединение готово к передаче?

Comment: Круто! Поздравляю!
Спасибо, что поделились результатом. Они добавили `wrap_bio` в 3.5. К тому моменту мне уже пришлось расстаться с Пайтоном, поэтому я не знал о такой фишке.

Comment: Добавил в ваш пример код для отправки данных клиенту. Оформил как отдельный ответ, так как в комментарии код калечится до безобразия

Comment: Переписал свой пример, так как он затыкался на получении сообщений больше 12 кбайт.

Answer (score 2):

ОТВЕТ ИЗМЕНЁН: ИСПРАВЛЕН КОД ДЛЯ ЧТЕНИЯ ИЗ SSLObject

Соединение считается установленным в тот момент, когда корректно завершается функция `do_handshake`. Пока идёт handshake, эта функция выбрасывает исключение `SSLWantReadError`, чтобы сервер догрузил ещё сообщения от клиента.

Процесс отправки данных клиенту состоит из двух частей: шифрования данных и собственно отправки. Шифрует `SSLObject.write`, шифртекст записывается в исходящий буфер. Достаточно отправить клиенту содержимое этого буфера.

Процесс чтения устроен хитрее. Есть сообщения протокола TLS во входящем сокете, есть сообщения во входящем буфере, есть расшифрованные данные в `SSLObject`.

Процесс расшифрования запускает метод `SSLObject.read()`. Данные в протоколе TLS передаются блоками TLS Record, поэтому может быть такая ситуация, что входящий буфер не пуст, но целого блока там нет. В этом случае будет исключение `SSLWantReadError` - нужно дочитать блок из буфера сокета в буфер SSL.

Кроме того, чисто экспериментально я установил, что `SSLObject.read` вычерпывает далеко не все данные из входящего буфера, поэтому функция `read_from_client` читает до тех пор, пока не опустошит весь буфер, либо будет исключение.

```py
import ssl
import socket

incom = ssl.MemoryBIO()
outcom = ssl.MemoryBIO()

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS)
context.check_hostname = False
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
context.load_cert_chain(certfile="cert1.pem", keyfile="privkey1.pem")

sslo = context.wrap_bio(incom, outcom, server_side=True)

serversocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
serversocket.bind(('', 8001))
serversocket.listen(1)

def send_to_client(plaintext):
    sslo.write(plaintext)
    # outcom holds ciphertext
    if outcom.pending > 0:
        resp = outcom.read()
        clientsocket.send(resp)
        print("DEBUG: write: sent {} bytes".format(len(resp)))

def read_from_client():
    plaintext = b''
    while True:
        try:
            data = sslo.read()
            plaintext += data
            if sslo.pending() == 0 and incom.pending == 0:
                # Received all text that was deciphered by now
                return plaintext, None
        except BaseException as err:
            # sslo.read might throw ssl.SSLWantReadException if the chunk 
            # of ciphertext is incomplete
            return plaintext, err

(clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
send_greeting = True
message = b''

while True:
    req = clientsocket.recv(4096)
    if len(req) == 0:
        # Connection closed
        break
    print("DEBUG: received ciphertext", len(req))
    incom.write(req)
    try:
        # if handshake is established already, does nothing
        sslo.do_handshake()
        # Handshake is over, `sslo` is ready to read/write
        if send_greeting :
            send_greeting = False
            send_to_client(b'Hello from ssl server.\n')
        data, err = read_from_client()
        message += data
        if err:
            raise err

    except ssl.SSLWantReadError:
        # (outcom.pending == 0) means that we have left some pieces of the ciphertext in 
        # the socket. Continue the loop and read it.
        if outcom.pending > 0:
            resp = outcom.read()
            clientsocket.send(resp)
            print("DEBUG: SSLWantReadError: sent {} bytes".format(len(resp)))
    except ssl.SSLWantWriteError:
        # SSL needs more data to produce output
        # Just go to the beginning of the loop and wait for the client
        continue
    except:
        # connection closed?
        break

print("DEBUG: Data left: sslo.pending(), incom.pending, outcom.pending",
    sslo.pending(), incom.pending, outcom.pending)

print("Plaintext received: ", len(message))
```

Тестировал при помощи `s_client`:

```
cat some.log | openssl s_client localhost:8001
```

Вывод команды s_client:

```
Hello from ssl server.
DONE
```

Лог сервера:

```
DEBUG: received ciphertext 311
DEBUG: SSLWantReadError: sent 1794 bytes
DEBUG: received ciphertext 93
DEBUG: write: sent 294 bytes
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 1147
DEBUG: Data left: sslo.pending(), incom.pending, outcom.pending 0 0 0
Plaintext received:  58228
```

s_client напечатал приветствие сервера и переслал весь файл.

Удивительное дело, но тестирование с `socat` не удалось. `socat` почему-то не досылает последние 20-с-небольшим байтов тестового лога.

Команда `socat open:some.log openssl:localhost:8001,verify=0` зависает. Если процесс прервать, то сервер выдаёт вот какой лог:

```
DEBUG: received ciphertext 4096
DEBUG: received ciphertext 1124
DEBUG: Data left: sslo.pending(), incom.pending, outcom.pending 0 0 0
Plaintext received:  58205
```

Видно, что `socat` не дослал 23 байта по сравнению с `s_client`. Соответственно, и данные на стороне сервера тоже меньше на 23 байта.

Comment: Сокат буферизует, если пошлешь ему eof то сбросит 23 байта мне кажется

Comment: У меня в реальном приложении сообщения гуляют в обе стороны по 60-100 байт.)

Comment: Это какие-то проблемы на стороне `socat`. `s_client` и `ncat` отработали без потерь. Никогда мне `socat` не нравился - какой-то универсальный комбайн с вертикальным взлётом и посадкой. Чуйка не обманула. Не дорабатывает!